# fork() client to achieve non-blocking IO

Tags: c, sockets

I want to implement a client socket that has non-blocking I/O.

i.e. a single client in a terminal will fork() upon receiving a command from stdin, then this child client will connect to a fork()'d server child, process the request, get an output, and then somehow return that output to the terminal of the parent client.

I have currently implemented everything besides the fork()-ing of the client, as I do not know how I need to go about returning the output of the child clients to the parent client so that they can be displayed.

How would I do this? I assume the basic structure is:

```
if ((childPID = fork()) == -1) {
    // Error
}
// Child process
else if (childPID == 0) {
    // send() to server
    // recv() from server 
    // format output
} 
// Parent process
else {
    // Display output of child clients if ready (?)
}
```

Since this will handle multiple commands at once, I am also not entirely sure how I go about "waiting" for the next output to show. Say for example one child process wanted to hold output until the user pressed "enter", then how would I tell other child clients to wait in displaying their own output.

Comment: It seems that you might be interested in reading about [*pipes*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (though there are other [inter-process communication primitives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)). You might also want to read about the [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) call.

Comment: Use `pipe()` to create interprocess communication between processes. Or switch to `posix_threads` and do `posix_barrier_wait` or some `posix_semaphores`